# Is there any way to make sql LIKE statement work like that?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unicode

I'm new here. I'm using SQL Server 2008. And I have a question about the `LIKE` statement.

For example: I have a statement like:

```
WHERE CONTRACTORNAME LIKE N'%aeu od%'
```

And I want the output will contain the row where `CONTRACTORNAME is "ấệư ôđ"`.

So, basically, I want input English characters and search for Unicode characters also.

Is there any ways to achieve this ? Thanks alot. !

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Comment: I'm using microsoft SQL server 2008 express

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `COLLATE` modifier with an Accent Insensitive Collation
ie:

```
 WHERE CONTRACTORNAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI LIKE N'%aeu od%'
```